# Sharepoint List Definition with custom column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, column, list-definition, visual-studio-2013

Im working on Sharepoint 2010 project. I created farm solution with some list definitions. Now i would like to use [Autocomplete Lookup Field](https://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/) in one of list definition. But if I look on *Schema.xml* there is only option to define one of bulid in types (Lookup, Text, Note ...):

```
...
<Field Name="somecolumnname"  ID="{ffc04a65-d961-4660-958b-646025ee605c}"  DisplayName="ResolutionType" Type="Lookup" ShowField="Title"  List="Lists/somelist" />
...
```

Is there any option how to say that *somecolumname* will be of type  [AutcompleteLookupField](https://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/) deployed on same server?

Comment: What I have done before is to add a feature receiver to the feature and on  `FeatureActivated` go in an update the XML of the created column, specifically replacing the `Type=` part to be `AutocompleteLookup`

Comment: yes as you write ...there i need only supply right _type_ parameter value. thanks